# Request input returns null in Middleware

Tags: laravel, middleware

I'm guarding a route via a middleware check for a valid token, like thus;-

```
http://localhost:8097/init/my-secret-token


Route::get('/init/{token}', [MyController::class, 'init'])->middleware('validToken');


// Kernel.php
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'validToken' => \App\Http\Middleware\EnsureTokenIsValid::class,
 ];


// App/Http/Middleware/EnsureTokenIsValid.php
class EnsureTokenIsValid
{

 public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
 {
    dd($request->input('token')); // returns null

    if($request->input('token') !== 'my-secret-token'){
        return redirect('home');
    }
    return $next($request);
 }
}
```

`$request->input('token')` returns null for some reason? I've tried the following:-

http://localhost:8097/init/token/my-secret-token &
http://localhost:8097/init?token=my-secret-token - only receive a 400

Comment: Try to use `$request->route('token')`

Comment: Yep, that works, thanks. Looks like the docs are slightly misleading. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/middleware#assigning-middleware-to-routes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

have you tried:

```
$request->route('token')
```

This should take parameter directly from your route.